# React js:component needs browser-reload to show updated content

Tags: reactjs

I coded the process of acquiring new access  token via refresh token, and sending the new access token to get the data. When  I send get request I check if the status code is unauthorized or not, if so,I send refresh token and get access token back, then I set `data.unauthorized`,`false`, to reload the component automatically.But it does not happen, when the token expires the get request fails, and does not show  the list of product,I have to reload the page manually, to see the updated content. I want  to check status code ,to  send refresh token if necessary , get access token and see updated content in one reload. Here is my code below.

```
const List =()=>{
 const[data,set_data]=useState({unauthorized:false,data:[]});
 useEffect(()=>{
    let token=localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')
    if(data.unauthorized){
        console.log("expired")
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_refresh_token/',{refresh:token}) //getting new token via refresh token if the access token expired
        .then((response)=>{
            localStorage.setItem('access_token',response.data.access)
        })
       }
    let config={
        headers:{
            Authorization: "Bearer"+ " " + localStorage.getItem('access_token') 
        }
       }
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/',config)
    .then(res=>{
        set_data({data:res.data.map(element=>
              <tr>
                  <td>{element.name}</td>
                  <td>{element.price}</td>
                  <td>{element.expiration_date}</td>
              </tr>
       ),

       unauthorized:false
    }
       ); 
       return res
    })
    .catch((res)=>{
        if(res.response.status==401){
            console.error("TOKEN EXPIRED AND NEW TOKEN ADDED")
            set_data({
                unauthorized:true
            })
           } 
         })

 },[data.unauthorized,JSON.stringify(data.data)]) 
    return(
        <> 
        <table className={style_for_table.table}>
               <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Expiration Date</th>
              </tr>
              {data.data}
          </table>
        </>
       )
      } 
export default List
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your useEffect is not re-rendering after you set your data because react has a bit of an issue basing it's re-render on nested js state variables. Try decomposing your state variable into two seperate ones.

```js
const [authorized, setAuth] = useState(...)
const [data, setData] = useState(...)

useEffect(() => {}, [authorized])
```

I think that re-executing that useEffect depending on data is also useless since the only real parameter to take into consideration is the auth since nothing can really change the data apart from the useEffect from what I see of the snippet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir, I tried so, but the problem stays the same.

Comment: Could you walk us through the debug you did with the solution? if you put a console log at the first line of your useEffect, does the console get outputed when you refresh your token?

Comment: when I check the response status  the error is shown, state is updated and the component reloads, it  console.log("expired") works, and probably the rest of the code also works(it  gets the content with new refresh token,  and data is reloaded (after that I toggle the state in order to reload component and see content but does not work) but  in order the see the data I have to reload the page

Comment: Please post an edited version of your question or a sandbox with the updated code so that we can help you go forward

Answer (score 0):

After some hours I realized that  the way I was  updating states and setting  dependencies were completely wrong. Here is the updated version of my code:

```
const List =()=>{
   
    const[data,set_data]=useState([]);
    const[access_token,set_access_token]= useState(localStorage.getItem('access_token'))
  
 useEffect(()=>{
    let token=localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')

    let config={
        headers:{
            Authorization: "Bearer"+ " " + access_token  
          }
         }

    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/',config)
    .then(res=>{
        set_data(res.data.map(element=>
            <tr>
                <td>{element.name}</td>
                <td>{element.price}</td>
                <td>{element.expiration_date}</td>
            </tr>  ),
                )
       return res
    })
    .catch((res)=>{
        if(res.response.status==401){
           axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_refresh_token/',{refresh:token})
           .then((response)=>{
             localStorage.setItem('access_token',response.data.access)
              set_access_token(response.data.access)
           })
        }
    })

 },[access_token])

    return(
        <> 
          <table className={style_for_table.table}>
          <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Expiration Date</th>
              </tr>

              {data}
          </table>
      </>
    )
   }
export default List
```